# Assigning values to elements of list

Tags: python

When I have a for loop:

```
for row in list:
    row = something_or_other
```

It seems that sometimes I can assign a value (or append/extend etc.) directly to `row` and the `list` changes accordingly, and sometimes I have to do something roundabout like:

```
for row in list:
    list[list.index(row)] = something_or_other
```

What gives?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never reassign the value `row` (or in general, whatever your iterating variable is) like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
for x in lst:
    x = # code
```

because this is reassigning the variable `x` entirely (it's saying "forget that `x` was a member of a list").

However, if `x` is mutable, for example if it's a list, you can do:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
for x in lst:
    x.append(10)
```

and it will actually change the values (to `[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 10]]`). In technical terms, this is the difference between a [rebinding and mutating operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding#Rebinding_and_mutation).

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `lst[lst.index(row)]` results in [`O(n²)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation) performance instead of `O(n)`, and may cause errors if the list contains multiple identical items.

Instead, assign a new list, constructed with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
doubled = [n*2 for n in lst]
```

Alternatively, you can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you really want to modify the original list:

```
for i,n in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = n*2
```

Answer (score 1):

`row` in the for loop is just a name for the original (but re-assigning it inside the for - effectively breaks the link). So if it's mutable then you can use methods on it (such as `append`, `add`, `extend` etc...) which will reflect in the underlying object.

The correct idiom is to use:

```
for rowno, row in enumerate(some_list):
    some_list[rowno] = #...
```